# atomatize a select statement for few tables and rows using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to automatize to keep record of some queries in a postgres dB, all the tables I want to queries has the 3 first field with some uids but called different. I am trying to generate a list to parse through the same query the different tables I'm interested, running the query i.e. for table 1, table 2 table 3, querying the col1, col2, col3 and geom so I run this one for one of the table:

```
try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                      password="pwd",
                                      host="host",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, geom FROM table1 "
    
        cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
        print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I have tried to change the select to SELECT table1.[0], table1.[1], table1.[2], table1.geom FROM table1 to get the columns by its order... after some investigation i have found that postgresql doesn't allow this type of indexing.
I am trying to find how to parse i.e

```
try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                      password="pwd",
                                      host="host",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        tb= {table1, table2, table3}
        for t in tb:
             postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT {t}.[0], {t}.[1], {t}.[2], {t}.geom FROM {t}"
    
             cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
             print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")
             rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Have a look at Psycopg's [string composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html?highlight=identifier), which allows to safely use Python strings as table or column names in your SQL queries.

Comment: I'm not sure why you actually want to swap the whole SQL syntax, though: `select table1.<column-name>` etc. You mention something about "to get the columns by its order", but its' unclear to me what you mean by that. You seem to have the columns name already (col1, col2, col3, geom), so you can set up the order in query without a problem.

Comment: @9769953 not the 3 columns has the name like to uuid1_petrol_station, uuid2_trading_pst, uuid3_area, geom the other table uuid1_market, uuid2_trading_market, uuid3_area, geom same with the other tables, so as the fields has different name I want to query by the order that the column has in the table so 0,1 and 2 so i can parse the query any table which will return the 3 first columns plus geom which is in all the tables

Comment: So you assume a fixed order of the columns in your table? To be honest, while that may be true in practice, more generally that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: You can get the column names for a particular table from postgres itself, with [`information_schema` or `pg_catalog`]. You can then grab the first three items from that query, which gives you the first three column names. Then, you can use string composition to create the query to obtain your data.

Comment: YEs i have been digging and doesn't seems possible or as you said not good idea, i will be filtering the data through views and querying them specifying the views. Thanks

Comment: Views sounds like a nice idea. Good luck.